# Dynamic change element class in template based on model choices

Tags: css, django, class, model

I want to dynamically change an element class inside the template based on my model.

Here is my model:

```
class StockFlow(models.Model):

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (None, _('- Selecione -')),
        ('Entrada', (
                (1, _('Pedido')),
                (2, _('Pegou emprestado')),
                (3, _('Entrada simples')),
            )
        ),
        ('Saida', (
                (4, _('Venda')),
                (5, _('Emprestado')),
                (6, _('Saida simples')),
                (7, _('Avaria ou perda')),
                (8, _('Presente')),
            )
        ),
    )

    stock = models.ForeignKey('Stock')
    value = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    type = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=-1)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
```

I want to change the class based in if is "Entrada" or "Saida". How can I make this conditional statement to set my css class?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a combination of Django forms and template context to accomplish this functionality...

Create a ModelForm from class StockFlow.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class StockFlowForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StockFlow

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StockFlowForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['type'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'Entrada' if self.instance.type in [1,2,3] else 'Saida'
```

Now when you render this ModelForm in a template, the type field will have a dynamic class set to either 'Entrada' or 'Saida' depending upon the value of type.